# executing raspberry pi shell commands with python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

i need to execute this two shell commands in my raspberry pi through a python code:

```
cd Desktop\fm_transmitter-master
sudo python ./PiStation.py -f 96 example.mp3
```

but i cant figure out how to do this, someone can help me please?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cd Desktop\fm_transmitter-master', shell=True)
subprocess.call('sudo python ./PiStation.py -f 96 syria.mp3', shell=True)
```

executing the commands

Comment: Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it:

```
        path = "/home/pi/Desktop/fm_transmitter-master/"
        os.chdir(path)
        args = ["sudo", "python", "PiStation.py", "-f", "96", "song.mp3"]
        pi_station = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
desktop = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
script_path = os.path.join(desktop, 'fm_transmitter-master', 'PiStation.py')
song_path = os.path.join(desktop, 'fm_transmitter-master', 'syria.mp3')
subprocess.call('sudo python ' + script_path + ' -f 96 ' + song_path, shell=True)
```

Comment: thank you very much, i would also need to stop this process if a certian button is pressed, how can i do it?

Comment: What kind of button?

Comment: it is returning "syntax error" when i am trying to run it///why?

Comment: when i run the script it just popping a window that says SyntaxError and "invalid syntax"

Comment: string interpolation, f-string was added after Python 3.6. Which version do you have?

Comment: on the pi i dont sure(i think 3.o) but on my pc it is 3.7.3

Comment: changed some things. now getting subprocess not defined although i imported it at the beginning if the script///tried to pip install it and it failed to do it